# Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, composable, android-studio-girafee

I created a new Composable project with Android Studio (Giraffe), but it's showing the following error:

[image: error].

The project-level Gradle configuration is

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
}
```

The app-level Gradle configuration is

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.sample.chat"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sample.chat"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

I tried changing the JDK configuration, applying 'Invalidate Cache and Restart,' and downgrading the Kotlin plugins, but nothing helps me.

I need to compile my source so how to fix it ?

Additional Info :

**Os**     : Ubuntu
**IDE**    : Android Studio Giraffe
**Kotlin** : 1.8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared all Android studio configurations and reinstalled it. Now it's working fine.